# An identity derived from the Laplace transform

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

It seems that $$\int_0^t \int_0^l f(\tau) ~d \tau ~d l = \int_0^t z f(t-z) dz $$ since the Laplace transform of both sides is $F(s)/s^2$, where $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$: the left-hand side is integration corresponds to multiplication by $1/s$ in the Laplace domain while the right-hand side because convolution in the time domain is multiplication in the Laplace domain.

Is it possible to prove this identity directly without appealing to the Laplace transform?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: interchange order of integrations on the left, then a change of variable.